# Properties of Borel functional calculus for unbounded normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

The theorem below is the Borel functional calculus for **bounded** normal operators defined on complex Hilbert space. [image]

I'm now studying the case for **unbounded** normal operators which are densely defined on a complex Hilbert space.  It seems that the main definition can be generalised. However, for the properties of that definition, few issues related to the domain of the operator appears if we want generalise the same property. For, example as for the property (iv) above, the commutative property $ST =TS$ should include the assertion that the domain of $ST$ equals that of $TS.$

My question is: If we assume that $T,S$ commute on the common domain and that $f(T) (D(S)) \subset D(S),$ can we prove that 
$$Sf(T)x  = f(T)Sx, \forall x\in D(S)$$

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I suspect that you need commutativity of the spectral projectors, commutativity of $S$ and $T$ might not be enough. [This is treated in Section 4 of Appendix 1](https://books.google.es/books?id=sU6j9Xdp7uIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA407#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Berezin-Shubin's "The Schrödinger's Equation".

Comment: In the same reference where I cut the theorem above, commutativity with spectral projections is equivalent to commutativity of $T,S.$ Sure this is true in the case of **bounded** operators. I don't see where is the difference !

Comment: I don't know precisely, but the unbounded case may be more subtle. That's what I understand from a quick reading of Berezin - Shubin.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unbounded+operator See "Nelson example". This is taken from the first volume of Reed and Simon, search "Formal manipulation is a touchy business".

Comment: This example shows that the naive definition of commuting operators has unwanted consequences in the unbounded case